# How to convert image to csv and save in python

Tags: python, csv, save, export-to-csv, spyder

This is my code that loads the pictures from the folder and lists their parameters sequentially. I need to not parse the parameters but save them as an csv file.How would you solve it

```
import requests
import os
import csv
import time


BASE_URL = 'https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect'
headers = {
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'd7264e9252674c9292b0d8b295cf3251',
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
}
parameters = {
    'returnFaceId': 'true',
    'returnFaceLandmarks': 'false',
    'returnFaceAttributes': 'age,gender,emotion'
}

def post_image(img_data):
    response = requests.post(BASE_URL, params=parameters,
                             headers=headers, data=img_data)
    try:
        return response.json()
    except:
        return None



img_path = 'C:\\Users\\Pifko\\Desktop\\bakalarka\\ffmpeg-20181107-0c6d4e7-win64-static\\ffmpeg-20181107-0c6d4e7-win64-static\\bin\\all'

files = os.listdir(img_path)

for file in files:
    file = os.path.join(img_path,file)
    img_data = open(file, 'rb').read()
    print(post_image(img_data))
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Ok, but what is your question? Do you get errors? If so, please show the traceback

Comment: Just save it json, it's better than CSV IMO and you didn't specify why so...